# Installing Roundcube with MSSQL Server 2016 not recognized

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, iis, roundcube

1. PHP 7.1.2
2. Roundcube 1.2.3 - Complete
3. SQL Server 2016
4. Windows Server 2016

Downloaded Microsoft PHP drivers (SQLSRV40.EXE) from:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/step-1-configure-development-environment-for-php-development

I get the following error message when trying to run the Roundcube installer and unable to continue:

> Sorry but your webserver does not meet the requirements for Roundcube!
>   Please install the missing modules or fix the php.ini settings according to the > above check results.
>   Hint: only checks showing NOT OK need to be fixed.

Nothing is marked as "NOT OK" on the entire page, however the database does not appear to be recognized. See the following copied from the installer page:

> Checking available databases
>
> Check which of the supported extensions are installed. At least one of them is required.
>
> MySQL:  NOT AVAILABLE(See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)
>
> PostgreSQL:  NOT AVAILABLE(See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.php)
>
> SQLite:  NOT AVAILABLE(See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php)
>
> SQLite (v2):  NOT AVAILABLE(See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php)
>
> SQL Server (SQLSRV):  NOT AVAILABLE(See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php)
>
> SQL Server (DBLIB):  NOT AVAILABLE(See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php)
>
> Oracle:  NOT AVAILABLE(See http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oci8.php)

I have verified the Microsoft drivers are in the PHP extension directory and attempted to include the following extensions (one at a time) in PHP.ini:

> extension=php_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll
>
> extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts_x64.dll

I have also tried other various SQL related extensions and restarted IIS and/or Windows with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the SQLSRV dll files must match the version of your PHP. I installed PHP 7.1 and attempted to use Microsoft's 7.0 driver.

After locating the proper driver from GitHub.com/Microsoft/... it placed the "OK" next to the MS SQLSRV and enabled the "Next" button to continue the RoundCube WebMail install.

Comment: Microsoft's SQL Server PHP 7.1 Drivers:
https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/4.1.5-Windows

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu 16 operating system try to run

```
php -m
```

if mysqli is not shown after running this command then install mysqli
For PHP 7.0 version

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysqli
```

For PHP 5 version

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqli
```